# Update table field with php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have created a stock portfolio to try and learn PHP and I am trying to have the price field update automatically every 30 seconds.  **I am able to display the prices but they all display on one price field on the same row. I want to display them on each of the rows. I have attached a screenshot of what it looks like right now.**

I have the portfolio table created and filled in with all the stocks the user has. Here is the code for showing the portfolio.

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Shares</th>
        <th>Last Price</th>
        <th>Market value</th>
        </tr>
<?php foreach ($shares as $row): ?>

        <tr >
        <td><?php echo $row["symbol"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["shares"];?></td>
        <td id="price">$<?php echo number_format($row["price"],2);?></td>    
        <td>$<?php echo number_format($row["total"],2);?></td>
        </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>


<tr>
    <td>Portfolio Value</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$<?php echo number_format($value, 2);?></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cash available</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$<?php echo number_format($cash[0]["cash"], 2);?></td>
</tr>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/update.js" ></script>
```

I then created a javascript file called update.js that calls update.php file every 30 seconds in order to update the price. Here is the code for update.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var updater = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#price').load('update.php', 'update=true');
    },10);   
});
```

update.php creates a $shares array with the user's stocks and sends it to portfolio_update.php to display it. This is the code for update.php

```
<?php

require("../includes/functions.php"); 
require("../includes/config_update.php");

$rows = query("SELECT * FROM shares WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
$cash = query("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
        //create array to store the shares
    $shares = array();

    //for each of the user info

    foreach($rows as $row){

        $stock = lookup($row["symbol"]);

        if($stock !== false){

            $shares[] = array(

                "price" => $stock["price"],
                "total" => $row["shares"]*$stock["price"]
            );         
        }
    }
    $size = count($shares);
    $value = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){

            $value  += $shares[$i]["total"];             
        }      

            extract($shares); 

require("../templates/portfolio_update.php");

?>
```

In portfolio_update.php I am displaying the prices but they all display on one price field. I want to display them on each of the rows. This is the portfolio_update.php code.

```
 <?php

            foreach ($shares as $rows ) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo number_format($rows["price"],2);  
            echo "</td>";           
            echo "</tr>";

            }               
    ?> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/update.js" ></script>
```

[image: screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: In you JS you only update one field (that with id `price`). Instead of the id you could make it a class and call `$.each(".price")` to work with each single row in your JS

Comment: I modified my JS file and now I get both prices on both rows `$(document).ready(function(){
        var updater = setTimeout(function(){
            $('.price').each(function () { 
             $(this).load('update.php', 'update=true');
            });
        },10);   
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `id`s to `class`es. You can't have duplicate `id`s in HTML. And modify your selector in jQuery accordingly (`jQuery('.price')`).

As a side note, lines 6 and 7 of update.php look like they *might* be prone to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I can't see what `query` does, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I changed prices to be a class and changed the JS code and it looks like this now `$(document).ready(function(){
        var updater = setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('.price').each(function () { 
             $(this).load('update.php', 'update=true');
            });
        },10);   
    });`
Now I get both prices on both rows next to each other. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. This is the line of HTML `<td class="price">$<?php echo number_format($row["price"],2);?></td>`

Comment: What does your output look like now (after the JavaScript is executed).

Comment: `Last Price  
26.12802.27  
26.12802.27`